# How to update every dictionary in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python

I have a dictionary that look like this

```py
[
    {'name': 'Apple', 'weight': 500, 'description': 'Apple is one of the most nutritious and healthiest fruits. It is very rich in antioxidants and dietary fiber. Moderate consumption can not only increase satiety, but also help promote bowel movements. Apple also contains minerals such as calcium and magnesium, which can help prevent and delay bone loss and maintain bone health. It is good for young and old.'},
    {'name': 'Avocado', 'weight': 200, 'description': 'Avocado contains large amount of oleic acid, a type of monounsaturated fat that can replace saturated fat in the diet, which is very effective in reducing cholesterol levels. Avocado is also high in fiber. Its soluble fiber can remove excess cholesterol from the body, while its insoluble fiber helps keep the digestive system functioning and prevent constipation.'},
    {'name': 'Blackberry', 'weight': 150, 'description': 'Blackberries have high nutritional value and are excellent fruit for health. It is rich in nutrients, various amino acids and trace elements necessary for the human body. They are good at promoting blood coagulation, delaying aging, improving immunity and reducing blood pressure and blood lipids. Blackberries can be consumed directly as fruit or made into jam and fruit wine.'},
    {'name': 'Grape', 'weight': 200, 'description': 'Grapes have up to 30% of sugar. A large amount of fruit acid in grapes helps digestion. Eating proper amount of grapes can strengthen the spleen and stomach. Grapes also contain the minerals calcium, potassium, phosphorus, iron, glucose, fructose, protein, tartaric acid, and various vitamins, which have strong nutritional functions and improve the function of the human body.'},
    {'name': 'Kiwifruit', 'weight': 250, 'description': 'Kiwifruit contains rich vitamin C, which can strengthen the immune system and supplement the nutrients consumed by the brain. Its perfect ratio of low sodium and high potassium can replenish the energy lost by working long hours.'},
    {'name': 'Lemon', 'weight': 300, 'description': 'Lemon is rich in vitamin C, which can improve immunity, accelerate wound healing and prevent colds. In the long run, it can lower the chance of developing cancer. Lemon juice helps reduce the burden on the digestive system and promotes the release of toxins from the body.'},
    {'name': 'Mango', 'weight': 300, 'description': 'Mango contains higher levels of vitamin C than ordinary fruits. Eating mango can also reduce cholesterol and triglycerides, and help prevent cardiovascular disease. Due to its high level of vitamins, regular consumption of mango play an important role in improving body function and moisturizing the skin.'},
    {'name': 'Plum', 'weight': 150, 'description': 'Plums are rich in sugar, vitamins, fruit acids, amino acids and other nutrients. With high nutritional value, Plums have outstanding health-care functions, which includes refreshing and nourishing liver, relieving depression and poisoning, and clearing dampness and heat of the human body.'},
    {'name': 'Strawberry', 'weight': 240, 'description': 'Strawberries are rich in carotene and vitamin A, which can alleviate night blindness, maintain the health of epithelial tissues, nourish the liver, and promote body growth and development. Strawberries contains large amount of dietary fiber as well, which can promote gastrointestinal motility and food digestion in the gastrointestinal tract.'},
    {'name': 'Watermelon', 'weight': 500, 'description': 'Watermelon is good for relieving heat, eliminating annoyance and quenching thirst. It contains a lot of water, which is good for relieving the symptoms of acute fever immediately. The sugar and salt contained in watermelon can diuretic and eliminate kidney inflammation. Watermelon also contains substances that can lower blood pressure.'}
]
```

What I want to do is updating every dictionary in that list with key is image_name and value is element in `os.listdir(directory)`. When I tried to do this:

```py
for a_dict in list_of_dictionary:
    for image in os.listdir(dir_image):
        a_dict.update(image_name = image)
```

It ended up with result like this:

```py
[
    {'name': 'Apple', 'weight': 500, 'description': 'Apple is one of the most nutritious and healthiest fruits. It is very rich in antioxidants and dietary fiber. Moderate consumption can not only increase satiety, but also help promote bowel movements. Apple also contains minerals such as calcium and magnesium, which can help prevent and delay bone loss and maintain bone health. It is good for young and old.', 'image_name': '010.txt'},
    {'name': 'Avocado', 'weight': 200, 'description': 'Avocado contains large amount of oleic acid, a type of monounsaturated fat that can replace saturated fat in the diet, which is very effective in reducing cholesterol levels. Avocado is also high in fiber. Its soluble fiber can remove excess cholesterol from the body, while its insoluble fiber helps keep the digestive system functioning and prevent constipation.', 'image_name': '010.txt'},
    {'name': 'Blackberry', 'weight': 150, 'description': 'Blackberries have high nutritional value and are excellent fruit for health. Itâ€™s rich in nutrients, various amino acids and trace elements necessary for the human body. They are good at promoting blood coagulation, delaying aging, improving immunity and reducing blood pressure and blood lipids. Blackberries can be consumed directly as fruit or made into jam and fruit wine.', 'image_name': '010.txt'},
    {'name': 'Grape', 'weight': 200, 'description': 'Grapes have up to 30% of sugar. A large amount of fruit acid in grapes helps digestion. Eating proper amount of grapes can strengthen the spleen and stomach. Grapes also contain the minerals calcium, potassium, phosphorus, iron, glucose, fructose, protein, tartaric acid, and various vitamins, which have strong nutritional functions and improve the function of the human body.', 'image_name': '010.txt'},
    {'name': 'Kiwifruit', 'weight': 250, 'description': 'Kiwifruit contains rich vitamin C, which can strengthen the immune system and supplement the nutrients consumed by the brain. Its perfect ratio of low sodium and high potassium can replenish the energy lost by working long hours.', 'image_name': '010.txt'},
    {'name': 'Lemon', 'weight': 300, 'description': 'Lemon is rich in vitamin C, which can improve immunity, accelerate wound healing and prevent colds. In the long run, it can lower the chance of developing cancer. Lemon juice helps reduce the burden on the digestive system and promotes the release of toxins from the body.', 'image_name': '010.txt'},
    {'name': 'Mango', 'weight': 300, 'description': 'Mango contains higher levels of vitamin C than ordinary fruits. Eating mango can also reduce cholesterol and triglycerides, and help prevent cardiovascular disease. Due to its high level of vitamins, regular consumption of mango play an important role in improving body function and moisturizing the skin.', 'image_name': '010.txt'},
    {'name': 'Plum', 'weight': 150, 'description': 'Plums are rich in sugar, vitamins, fruit acids, amino acids and other nutrients. With high nutritional value, Plums have outstanding health-care functions, which includes refreshing and nourishing liver, relieving depression and poisoning, and clearing dampness and heat of the human body.', 'image_name': '010.txt'},
    {'name': 'Strawberry', 'weight': 240, 'description': 'Strawberries are rich in carotene and vitamin A, which can alleviate night blindness, maintain the health of epithelial tissues, nourish the liver, and promote body growth and development. Strawberries contains large amount of dietary fiber as well, which can promote gastrointestinal motility and food digestion in the gastrointestinal tract.', 'image_name': '010.txt'},
    {'name': 'Watermelon', 'weight': 500, 'description': 'Watermelon is good for relieving heat, eliminating annoyance and quenching thirst. It contains a lot of water, which is good for relieving the symptoms of acute fever immediately. The sugar and salt contained in watermelon can diuretic and eliminate kidney inflammation. Watermelon also contains substances that can lower blood pressure.', 'image_name': '010.txt'}
]
```

How to make value of image_name is 001, 002, ..., 010 not only 010?

Comment: You want all the filename as a list `image_name` in ?

Comment: Do you mean that, in the end, Apple has image_name 001.txt, Avocado has image_name 002.txt, and so on ?

Comment: @Programmer exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can zip together the list of images from `os.listdir` and a list with numbers from 0 to the length of the list of dictionaries, iterate over that and assign each image name to its dictionary:

```py
dict_list = [
    {'name': 'Apple', 'weight': 500, 'description': 'Apple is one of the most nutritious and healthiest fruits. It is very rich in antioxidants and dietary fiber. Moderate consumption can not only increase satiety, but also help promote bowel movements. Apple also contains minerals such as calcium and magnesium, which can help prevent and delay bone loss and maintain bone health. It is good for young and old.'},
    {'name': 'Avocado', 'weight': 200, 'description': 'Avocado contains large amount of oleic acid, a type of monounsaturated fat that can replace saturated fat in the diet, which is very effective in reducing cholesterol levels. Avocado is also high in fiber. Its soluble fiber can remove excess cholesterol from the body, while its insoluble fiber helps keep the digestive system functioning and prevent constipation.'},
    {'name': 'Blackberry', 'weight': 150, 'description': 'Blackberries have high nutritional value and are excellent fruit for health. It is rich in nutrients, various amino acids and trace elements necessary for the human body. They are good at promoting blood coagulation, delaying aging, improving immunity and reducing blood pressure and blood lipids. Blackberries can be consumed directly as fruit or made into jam and fruit wine.'},
    {'name': 'Grape', 'weight': 200, 'description': 'Grapes have up to 30% of sugar. A large amount of fruit acid in grapes helps digestion. Eating proper amount of grapes can strengthen the spleen and stomach. Grapes also contain the minerals calcium, potassium, phosphorus, iron, glucose, fructose, protein, tartaric acid, and various vitamins, which have strong nutritional functions and improve the function of the human body.'},
    {'name': 'Kiwifruit', 'weight': 250, 'description': 'Kiwifruit contains rich vitamin C, which can strengthen the immune system and supplement the nutrients consumed by the brain. Its perfect ratio of low sodium and high potassium can replenish the energy lost by working long hours.'},
    {'name': 'Lemon', 'weight': 300, 'description': 'Lemon is rich in vitamin C, which can improve immunity, accelerate wound healing and prevent colds. In the long run, it can lower the chance of developing cancer. Lemon juice helps reduce the burden on the digestive system and promotes the release of toxins from the body.'},
    {'name': 'Mango', 'weight': 300, 'description': 'Mango contains higher levels of vitamin C than ordinary fruits. Eating mango can also reduce cholesterol and triglycerides, and help prevent cardiovascular disease. Due to its high level of vitamins, regular consumption of mango play an important role in improving body function and moisturizing the skin.'},
    {'name': 'Plum', 'weight': 150, 'description': 'Plums are rich in sugar, vitamins, fruit acids, amino acids and other nutrients. With high nutritional value, Plums have outstanding health-care functions, which includes refreshing and nourishing liver, relieving depression and poisoning, and clearing dampness and heat of the human body.'},
    {'name': 'Strawberry', 'weight': 240, 'description': 'Strawberries are rich in carotene and vitamin A, which can alleviate night blindness, maintain the health of epithelial tissues, nourish the liver, and promote body growth and development. Strawberries contains large amount of dietary fiber as well, which can promote gastrointestinal motility and food digestion in the gastrointestinal tract.'},
    {'name': 'Watermelon', 'weight': 500, 'description': 'Watermelon is good for relieving heat, eliminating annoyance and quenching thirst. It contains a lot of water, which is good for relieving the symptoms of acute fever immediately. The sugar and salt contained in watermelon can diuretic and eliminate kidney inflammation. Watermelon also contains substances that can lower blood pressure.'}
]
image_dir = "path/to/dir/containing/images"
for dct, image in zip(dict_list, os.listdir(image_dir)):
    dct["image_name"] = image
```

Comment: @AchmadSetiawan please accept the answer that helped you most by clicking the grey checkmark on the left of it. That gives both you and the answerer some reputation.

Comment: Since dictionaries are mutable you can iterate over the dictionaries and mutate them, no need for indexing. In this example it will something like: `for a_dict, image in zip(dict_list, os.listdir(image_dir)):
    a_dict["image_name"] = image`

Comment: @RoyCohen oh thanks, I thought about that way but thought it would not modify the dicts in dict_list, but only the local copies.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a list and append to it. Currently, you are just overwriting with the last value.

```
for a_dict in list_of_dictionary:
    for image in os.listdir(dir_image):
        if 'image_name' in a_dict:
            a_dict['image_name'].append(image)
        else:
            a_dict['image_name']= [image]
```

You can use `setdefault` to get rid of `if-else` block:

```
for a_dict in list_of_dictionary:
    for image in os.listdir(dir_image):
        a_dict.setdefault('image_name', []).append(image)
```

---

Update: You can use `zip()` for the desired output but you need to be sure that the number of images and the dictionary elements are same:

```
images = [for image in os.listdir(dir_image)]
for a_dict, image in zip(list_of_dictionary, images):
    a_dict.update('image_name' = image)
```

Comment: thankyou for your answer. But, the result would be a a list which not what i want. i want that every dictionary have its own unique value of image_name. as an example for apple the value of image name would be 001 and for blackberry would be 002, etc

Comment: are you sure the sizes are same then? if yes, then you can `zip()` in that case. please see updated answer.